# QMap чтение элементов

Tags: c++, qt5, c++11

Не получается прочитать элементы. Рассматривал разные варианты, но все они почему то не работают. Буду признателен за помощь.

```
QMap <QString, QString> q2;

int iter;
q2.Iterator iter;
for( iter = q2.begin(); iter != q2.end(); ++iter )
{
    qDebug() << iter.key() << " : " << iter.value();
}
```

выдаёт ошибки

```
/home/alexandr/Documents/Job/EmailQT/EmailQT/del_duble_sql.cpp:42: error: invalid use of 'QMap<QString, QString>::Iterator'
     q2.Iterator iter;
        ^
/home/alexandr/Documents/Job/EmailQT/EmailQT/del_duble_sql.cpp:43: error: cannot convert 'QMap<QString, QString>::iterator' to 'int' in assignment
     for( iter = q2.begin(); iter != q2.end(); ++iter )
               ^
/home/alexandr/Documents/Job/EmailQT/EmailQT/del_duble_sql.cpp:43: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'int' and 'QMap<QString, QString>::iterator')
     for( iter = q2.begin(); iter != q2.end(); ++iter )
                                  ^
/home/alexandr/Documents/Job/EmailQT/EmailQT/del_duble_sql.cpp:45: error: request for member 'key' in 'iter', which is of non-class type 'int'
         qDebug() << iter.key() << " : " << iter.value();
                          ^
/home/alexandr/Documents/Job/EmailQT/EmailQT/del_duble_sql.cpp:45: error: request for member 'value' in 'iter', which is of non-class type 'int'
         qDebug() << iter.key() << " : " << iter.value();
                                                 ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не "не получается", это вы синтаксис не знаете. Для доступа к декларациям внутри типа нужно использовать `::`

```
QMap <QString, QString> q2;


for(QMap <QString, QString>::iterator iter = q2.begin(); iter != q2.end(); ++iter )
{
    qDebug() << iter.key() << " : " << iter.value() << std::endl;
}
```

В С++11 есть прекрасное ключевое слово `auto`, специально для таких случаев:

```
for(auto iter = q2.begin(); iter != q2.end(); ++iter )
{
    qDebug() << iter.key() << " : " << iter.value() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: В `c++11` ещё удобнее будет использовать _range-for_

Answer (score 2):

**Первая ошибка**:

> /home/alexandr/Documents/Job/EmailQT/EmailQT/del_duble_sql.cpp:42: error: invalid use of 'QMap::Iterator'
>        q2.Iterator iter;

Тип переменной указывается совершенно не так. Можно либо через фактический тип другой переменной:

```
QMap<QString, QString>::iterator iter;
```

либо (начиная с C++11) через `decltype`:

```
decltype(q2)::iterator iter;
```

---

**Вторая и последующая ошибки:**

> /home/alexandr/Documents/Job/EmailQT/EmailQT/del_duble_sql.cpp:43: error: cannot convert 'QMap::iterator' to 'int' in assignment
>        for( iter = q2.begin(); iter != q2.end(); ++iter )
>
> ...

У вас объявлены две переменные с именем `iter`:

```
int iter;
q2.Iterator iter;
```

Уберите первое объявление.